# Is there a way to invoke a leftclick in python?

Tags: python, windows, automation, mouse, ctypes

I only have the python 2.6. Can I do this without using external libraries? I just want to perform a left click wherever the cursor currently is.

Comment: First, do you have PyWin32, or does that count as "external libraries"? Second, do you want the mouse click emulated at the level of "sending the same Windows message to the window that would have received the click", or do you want to be able to fool lower-level stuff as well?

Comment: Hi, I just checked I don't have pywin32. As for events I won't use them but I need the window to receive the click event as if I clicked it. So not sure if that requires the lower level stuff?

Comment: The word "event" is a bit ambiguous in Windows terminology, but forget about that. If you just want to fool the window being clicked, and don't care about anything else, you don't need the lower-level stuff. Which is good, because that can get painful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, first you have to know how to open the user32 windll via `ctypes`, which is [trivial](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries):

```
from ctypes import *
user32 = windll.user32
```

Next, the Win32 function you want to call is probably [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), although you might want to look at `mouse_event` and possibly `SendMessage` (and the documentation for which WM_* messages correspond to a mouse click) to compare and contrast.

Assuming you go with `SendInput`, you're going to send one `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` followed by one `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP`, with 0 for all of the params besides `dwFlags`.

So, how do you call this? Well, here's the C API:

```
UINT WINAPI SendInput(
  _In_  UINT nInputs,
  _In_  LPINPUT pInputs,
  _In_  int cbSize
);
```

That `LPINPUT` means you've got a pointer to an array of [`INPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structures. Since the `INPUT` structure itself has a union of `MOUSEINPUT`, `KBDINPUT`, and `HARDWAREINPUT`, you'll also need to define those (although you can get away with  just defining the first and pretending the others don't exist, since the first is the only one you need).

So, the steps to doing this with `ctypes` are:

- Define the [`Structure`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions)s for [`MOUSEINPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`INPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- Load the `user32` windll.
- Set the [`argtypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes) for `user32.SendInput`.
- Create your first `MOUSEINPUT` instance, with `dwFlags= MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN`, and the `INPUT` instance to go with it.
- Call `user32.SendInput(1, [myinput], len(INPUT))` or `user32.SendInput(1, addressof(myinput), len(INPUT))` or whatever (depending on how you defined the `argtypes`).
- Create your second `MOUSEINPUT` instance, with `dwFlags= MOUSEEVENTF_LEFT`, and the `INPUT` instance to go with it.
- Call `user32.SendInput()` again.

One last note: On Vista and above, you have to have the right "integrity level" to do this. For example, a normal app cannot send a click to an "elevated" app (e.g., an installer). Hopefully this isn't an issue for you. If it is, you need to read up on UIPI and UAC… and if worst comes to worst, you may need to fall back to lower-level tricks.

Is that enough, or do you need help with some specific part of this?

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful. I ended up using ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_CLICK, 0, 0, 0, 0), what's the difference between this and SendInput? I haven't tried your method, but in the 2nd answer of this, I tried his SendInput but it had stuff like pointer(x) which returned undefined errors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964051/python-win32-simulate-click

Comment: Well, `SendInput` can do things that `mouse_event` can't, but you don't care about that. So the only real difference is that `mouse_event` is "superseded", and may be deprecated and eventually removed. As long as you don't anticipate needing to support Windows 9 or 10 without any code changes, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks alot man, appreciate your detailed reply. Will be using it if I need to make changes in the future. Happs xmas :)